# OpenGL Error: 1282 when setting a uniform

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I have been trying to learn OpenGL for a while a create a simple 3d game, but upon trying to set uniforms nothing works anymore. I am using a quite old mac, but I don't think that that has anything to do with it.

This is my code for setting the uniform:

```
Texture texture = createTexture("./res/images/atlas.png");
bindTexture(&texture, 1);
setUniform1i(&shader, "u_Texture", 1);
```

The code for setUniform1i is:

```
void setUniform1i(const Shader *shader, char *name, int i1)
{
  int loc = getUniformLocation(shader, name);
  bindShader(shader);
  glUniform1i(loc, i1);
}
```

This is my fragment shader:

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D u_Texture;

varying vec2 v_texCoor;

void main()
{
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_texCoor);
    gl_FragColor = texColor;
}
```

One thing to note is that I can set a model view projection matrix uniform in my vertex shader just fine, so I have no idea why setting another uniform would result in an error.

Comment: For some weird reason, changing the name of my model view projection matrix uniform from u_mvp to literally anything else fixes everything. WHY DOES THIS WORK???

Answer (score 0):

Is your shader binding correctly? I had the same problem but it was resolve when binding it. `glUseProgram(program);`